# How can I find the bounds for x and y inorder to find the volume of solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: This is the question]

The problem is asking for the volume of the solid under the surface $z=x^3y^4+xy^2$ and above the region bounded by the curves $y=x^3-x$ and $y=x^2+x$ for $x \ge 0 $.

Comment: It's always a good idea to graph the situation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1vppahpp0s

Comment: I graphed in 3D but was still confused about the bounds

Comment: I have figure out the bounds as for y they are $x^3-x <= y <= x62+x$ and for x they are are $0<=x<=2$

Comment: So I think the integrand is $x^3 y^4 + xy^2$. And you can start by slicing it in the $x$-direction, with the length of each strip goes from $x^3-x$ to $x^2 -x$ ($0\leq x \leq 2$).

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, it looks good. So I think the final expression is something like
$$
\int_0^2 \int_{x^3-x}^{x^2+x} \left(x^3 y^4 + xy^2 \right)\, dy dx
$$